# Why can I implement NSDraggingDestination methods in a NSWindowController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I am working on using Cocoa's Drag & Drop API in a non-C environment. I'll have to use the objc/runtime.h functions and so I need to understand where exactly I have to inject the necessary methods.

Now, the SDK documentation says that one first calls registerForDraggedTypes on a NSView or a NSWindow object. It further explains that both these classes implement stubs of the NSDraggingDestination protocol, and that those stub methods would then need to be overwritten (at least draggingEntered: and performDragOperation: need to; the rest are optional).

So far so good.

However, I found that I can as well just implement these methods in the window's controller, i.e. in a class of type NSWindowController. As an example, I did this with Apple's "DemoMonkey" sample, where I implemented the required calls in its DisplayController (which is a NSWindowController) and then invoked registerForDraggedTypes on 'self.window'.

How can this work?

I mean, how does the object that received the registerForDraggedTypes call relate to the controller in this case, knowing that it has to ask it for these drag callbacks? Where is it documented that this works this way?

I wonder if this has to do with the fact that NSWindowController is a NSResponder. Does, in fact, the NSDraggingDestination invocation run through the responder chain? (For the record: I also tried to create a subclass of NSResponder, implement the callbacks there instead of in the controller class, create an instance of it and call "self.window makeFirstResponder:" with it, but that didn't lead to the callbacks being invoked when dragging data over the window.)

Can anyone clarify this behavior, and maybe explain where this fact is documented (or is this simply undoc'd behavior and should not be relied on, therefore?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you sent `registerForDraggedTypes:` to the window and NSWindowController is the delegate of the NSWindow.

This is mentioned in the "[Drag and Drop Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Concepts/dragdestination.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000977-BAJBJFBG)":

> Although NSDraggingDestination is declared as an informal protocol,
>   the NSWindow and NSView subclasses you create to adopt the protocol
>   need only implement those methods that are pertinent. (The NSWindow
>   and NSView classes provide private implementations for all of the
>   methods.) Either a window object or its delegate may implement these
>   methods; however, the delegate’s implementation takes precedence if
>   there are implementations in both places.

And the documentation for NSWindow's [registerForDraggedTypes:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/registerForDraggedTypes%3a):

> Registering an NSWindow object for dragged types automatically makes
>   it a candidate destination object for a dragging session. NSWindow has
>   a default implementation for many of the methods in the
>   NSDraggingDestination protocol. The default implementation forwards
>   each message to the delegate if the delegate responds to the selector
>   of the message. The messages forwarded this way are draggingEntered:,
>   draggingUpdated:, draggingExited:, prepareForDragOperation:,
>   performDragOperation:, and concludeDragOperation:.

This doesn't happen if you want to implement something like a "drop view" and call `registerForDraggedTypes:` on a NSView. Then you will need to forward all messages to the controller yourself. In either case, I think that the controller is a more suitable place for drag/drop handling code anyway.

Comment: I can't verify this now, but it sounds like you hit the nail on the head. Thanks!

Comment: "NSWindowController is the delegate of the NSWindow" it is not always true by default, for example for new template projects with storyboards

Comment: @AlexanderB I never said it is **always** true. I said that it is likely to be true in **this** case and therefore it is the cause for the behavior that was described in the question...